# python 2.7 converting to 3.4. Error in 3.4, when no error in 2.7

Tags: python-3.4

I have tested and used this code in python 2.4. However, as soon as I moved onto python 3.4, an error comes up - "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'. I would greatly appreciate it if you managed to find the reason why this is happening. I will post the code I used below

```
alphabetL = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
alphabetC = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
number = '0123456789'
space = ' '
Ll = len(alphabetL)
Lc = len(alphabetC)
Ln = len(number)
Lall = Ll + Lc + Ln
Question1 = input('Hello, please insert the message you want encrypted: ')
key1 = input('Please insert the key you want used [Keep between 1 and 26]: ')
cipher = ''
cipher2 = ''


for A in Question1:
    if A in alphabetL:
        cipher += alphabetL[(alphabetL.index(A)+key1)%Ll]
    elif A in alphabetC:
        cipher += alphabetC[(alphabetC.index(A)+key1)%Lc]
    elif A in number:
        cipher += number[(number.index(A)+key1)%Ln]
    elif A in space:
        cipher += space
    else:
        print ('Error, please use abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
print (cipher)
```

Comment: `input` in 3.x is like `raw_input` (which you should *already have been using*) in 2.x.

Comment: So why is an error coming up?

Comment: Because you have a string (e.g. `'1'`) not an integer (`1`), which is *exactly what the error message is telling you*.

Comment: okay, calm down. It's clear I'm a novice coder so could you please help me in a more practical way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a string as an index

```
cipher += alphabetL[(alphabetL.index(A)+key1)%Ll]
```

`alphabetL.index(A)` is an **integer** and `key1` is a **string**
so you must convert `key1` to **integer**.

```
key1 = int(input('Please insert the key you want used [Keep between 1 and 26]: '))
```